# v-if makes jquery clock picker stop working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my original div which clockpicker library works properly.

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="18:00">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Since I put  v-if in div attribute like this:

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker"  v-if="overtimeType==3">
```

The clock picker just does not pop up from the input field anymore. Console shows no error. Any idea why?

PS: v-show works just fine.

Comment: probably `overtimeType` is not 3

Comment: @gurghet sorry, I forgot to mention that, overtimeType  is actually 3 and div is really shown.

Comment: I tried your code and it works when `overtimeType` is 3. How are you setting the 3?

Answer (score 1):

When `v-if` evaluates to `false` it **removes** elements from dom, therefore one of two things may occur:

- `v-if` removed div with clockpicker class at the time `$('.clockpicker').clockpicker()` is executed, so no element will be found to call `.clockpicker()` on
- `v-if` removes element after `.clockpicker()` decorated it and clockpicker library watches its root element for dom removal events to detach itself

Things work properly with `v-show` because this directive toggles css display property instead of actually removing element from dom.

Comment: To make it work with `if`, the user would need to set up a hook to manage initialization of the widget. http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions